# Trying to Clear Columns based on time to trigger onEdit script automatically with an ArrayFormula in place

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying to get my onEdit script to run automatically as rows are added to my Google Spreadsheet. I already have the onEdit script working, and I have an arrayFormula set to add to new rows when added, but this isn't enough to trigger the onEdit. I can clear the contents of the column and that will trigger it, but I need to set a daily clearColumn function based on those rows marked "TRUE" and everything I try just keeps giving me an null/undefined.

**Here is my onEdit script: **

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Initial SS Addition
  // target sheet of move to named Google to Mailshake
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 9 or H
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Initial SS Addition" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Google to Mailshake");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Google to Mailshake" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Initial SS Addition");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

**Here is my arrayFormula: **

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(H:H)=1,"Appt Done",IF(ISBLANK(H:H),"",TODAY()>=datevalue(H:H))))
```

**And this is my currenty clearColumn script that is giving me issues: **

```
function clean0() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var where     = ss.getSheetByName('Initial SS Addition');
  var triggerCell = where.getRange('I:I').getValue();

  if (triggerCell == 'FALSE'){} else  // If the cell is true do nothing
  if (triggerCell == 'TRUE'){   // If the cell is false run the script


  sheet.getRangeList(range).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: Why not just use a time trigger?

Comment: onEdits only trigger on user edits

Comment: @TheMaster unfortunately I'm incredibly new to this script-writing game and can't figure out how to change it from an onEdit to a time trigger. If you know how I will gladly take the advice.

Comment: First look at the event object with`Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` assuming that e is the parameter you are using to hold the event object.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out:

Set up a time trigger as follows:

```
function createTimeTrigger() {
  // Creates a trigger to run the moveRows function every hour
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveRows')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(5)
      .create();
}
```

The removed the onEdit function and changed it to just a moveRows function:

```
function moveRows() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Initial SS Addition
  // target sheet of move to named Google to Mailshake
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 9 or H
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Initial SS Addition");
  if (!s) {
    return;
  }
  var columnI = s.getRange("I:I"); // gets the range of cells in column I
  var values = columnI.getValues(); // gets the values in the range
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    if (value == true) {
      var row = i + 1; // row index is 1-based
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Google to Mailshake");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Now it works perfectly. Thanks to everyone for the ideas :)